# Oracle total query executions with count and execution time (for Java program)

Tags: java, performance, oracle, plsql

I want to know total how many queries got executed with its count and execution time for my Java program (I dont have the source code).

I am planning to write PL/SQL which joins `gv$session` and `gv$sql`, logging output to one of the table. After program execution ends I will query the table to get more details.

But I wanted to know whether Oracle has any default utility to get similar report already?  I was looking at AWR reporting for Oracle but didn't get easy documentation for the same.

Comment: `Tkprof` is my instinctual answer, but I'll leave this for those who know better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with

```
DBMS_SESSION.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE (waits => true);
```

On the database server you will get a file generated (in the directory indicated by `user_dump_dest` in v$parameter) that will contain a trace.

Run that trace through the `tkprof` utility (database utility on the DB server) and it will give you all the SQLs, how many times they were executed, how long they spent executed and a breakdown of what that time was spent on.

The drawback of v$sql (or gv$sql for RAC) is that (1) some queries might be aged out, especially for a long running process and (2) potential 'interference' from other sessions if you don't haev exclusive access to the DB.

If you don't want to get into messaing around with files, from v$session you can also drill down to v$sessstat and v$session_event which can offer some useful tidbits.

```
select event, sum(round(time_waited/(100*60),2)) time_mins, wait_class
from v$session_event
where sid in (221)
group by event, wait_class
order by 2 desc;

select sid, name, value from v$sesstat s 
  join v$statname n on n.statistic# = s.statistic#
where s.sid in (221)
and name in ('consistent gets','sorts (rows)','execute count',
        'parse count (total)','user calls','user commits','user rollbacks'
order by value desc;
```

Comment: thanks Gary, I will try Trace in my environment.  BTW I have one more related question, as you know I am trying to use gv$session, gv$sql and gv$process to get active queries on server, by using these three tables, is there any way I can identify each query executed uniquely ? As an example if particular SELECT query runs 4 times in sequence in same session, can I distinguish each execution separately ?  I tried using SID, PID, SERIAL# etc fields but seems particular query shares same SID, PID etc in all executions

Comment: One possible issue with this is that its session specific.  If this java pgm uses connection pooling or a shared server env, not sure how to trace individual users or get consolidated reports.  I'm sure there's a clever way around this, but thought I'd bring it up.  Perhaps using dbms_monitor...I'd have to look more into that one.